# Find all solutions of $(xy^2+x)dx+(y-x^2y)dy=0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Find all solutions of $$(xy^2+x)dx+(y-x^2y)dy=0$$

<s>What I know is that:
Assuming $M=xy^2+x, N=y-x^2y$ then if $xN+yM\neq0$ then solution of above equation is unique for every point. In our case it is true when $x\neq0$ or $y\neq0$.</s>
However I do not know how to continue this one.

Well, what I've written above is not true because $M,N$ are not homogeneous.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can separate it out as $$\frac {ydy}{xdx} =\frac{y^2+1}{x^2-1} $$ now put $y^2+1=u $ and then continue to get a very simple integrable function.

Comment: So if $y^2+1=u$, then $dy=\frac{du}{2y}$, right?

Comment: No it should be $ydy/dx=du/dx $ y is always to be a function of x while dolving any differential equation

Comment: Well, it looks pretty much like that after substituion. If $dy=du/2y$, then $ydy/dx=du/2dx$. Or I am doing something wrong?

Comment: No its just the general way theres nothing wrong.

Answer (score 2):

Hint:

$$x(y^2+1)dx+y(1-x^2)dy=0 \implies x(y^2+1)dx=y(x^2-1)dy$$

Hence,

$$\frac{x}{x^2-1}dx=\frac{y}{y^2+1}dy\implies \frac{2x}{x^2-1}dx=\frac{2y}{y^2+1}dy.$$

The last equation can be simply integrated if you notice $d[\ln f(x)]/dx=f'(x)/f(x)$.

Comment: So all solutions of this final equation are unique. It works for all points when $x\neq1$ and $x\neq-1$.  When one of this possibilities is actual then we have $(y^2+1)dx=0$. But this is not possible, right?

Comment: For these cases, you will get $x= const$. But this does not represent a function.